# How to cancel current command in Chrome DevTools JavaScript console?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

How to cancel current command in Chrome DevTools JavaScript console?

<kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> does not work like it does on a normal shell CLI terminal, nothing happens.

I know I can press <kbd>Ctrl + L</kbd> to clear the console but that doesn't clear the current command I have typed out.

Current workaround is <kbd>Shift + home</kbd> then <kbd>delete</kbd> but that is not as efficient as I would like.

I also tried <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + P</kbd> and searched for `cancel` and `clear` but nothing is coming up.

Answer (score 1):

I have an answer for you (after quite some time searching the same thing myself)!

All 3 of the following work to (completely) clear the current chrome developer tools console command line (not the console itself) - if you **haven't** hit enter to actually run the command  yet.

*So for example: you used the up arrow to look through previous commands, and decide you don't want to use any and just want to clear the command line:*

1. "command delete"
2. "command shift delete"
3. "control u"

**The differences:**

"command delete" and "command shift delete"

- Work on only one console command line at a time:
- If you only have one line - it's the same as "control u"
- If you used "shift enter" to make your command line multi-line, these ones will only delete the current line (so you would have to hit it multiple times - 1 for each line).

"control u"

- Deletes the WHOLE current command line input, regardless of number of lines.

I hope that helps, since I could NOT find an answer for this anywhere either! Everyone is talking about clearing the console, but that doesn't affect the current non-executed command line!

*(However, I personally want to be able to still see what I was typing after I cancel it (like a terminal ctrl-c)... That, I have not figured out yet, so maybe someone else knows that part!!!)*